# firestore.collection is not function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Building Registration api for student with using of Firebase, already initialize Firebase.

trying all the different methods and see all the answer on stack overflow but still got the error and double check my Firebase initialize [error show in portman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZjOy.png)

```
const { error } = require('console');
const firebase = require('../db.js');
const Student = require('../models/student.js')
const firestore = require('../db.js');
const { collection, doc, setDoc, getDocs } = require("firebase/firestore");
// const firestore = firebase.firestore();


const addStudent = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = req.body;
        // await firestore.collection('students').doc().set(data);
        // collection(firestore, "students" )
        // const q = query(collection(firestore, "students".doc().set(data)));

        const docRef = doc(collection(firestore, 'students'));
        await setDoc(docRef, data);
        console.log(q,"q is");
        res.send('Record saved successfuly');
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have pointed out, you're using the **older API** syntax while I am importing the v9 SDK.

The message is about this line

```
firestore.collection("Students").doc(studentid).collection("links")
```

In the new modular syntax, that should be:

```
collection(firestore, "Students", StudentUid, "links")
```